# SQLite can't delete a value from the database

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I've got a problem with my sql command.
I created two related tables.

```
String CREATE_TABEL_1="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME2+"(idCategory INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, categoryName TEXT, pictureId INTEGER)";
String CREATE_TABLE_2="CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+"(idCategory INTEGER, date TEXT, weekOfYear INTEGER, time REAL," +
"FOREIGN KEY (idCategory) REFERENCES Category(idCategory) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE)";
```

And when I want to delete i.e. category "WORK" from Category (table 1), it's removed but work's id is not deleted from Table 2.

Comment: is your table  INNODb or MyIsam?

Comment: It's SQLite in android

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, foreign keys is supported by syntax but not enforced.

You need to enable foreign keys support with

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys=on;
```